# Spring Jdbc template Row mapper is not setting all values in Object

Tags: java, spring, oracle, tomcat

I am using spring jdbc template to retreive 400 records from oracle database. 
After that i am using row mapper to convert rows to objects. Some of the values in object are not having any values. when i test same sql in pl/sql editor, i am able to see all rows and all columns for rows. When i debug application, i am getting below error. If i fetch less number of records(7) for same query, it is working fine.Row mapper is setting all values for object. Can you please help me on this.

```
java.sql.SQLException: statement handle not executed

2017-02-09 15:45:39 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:317 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
2017-02-09 15:45:39 INFO  SQLErrorCodesFactory:126 - SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, Hana]
2017-02-09 15:45:39 WARN  SQLErrorCodesFactory:227 - Error while extracting database product name - falling back to empty error codes
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:305)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:329)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory.getErrorCodes(SQLErrorCodesFactory.java:214)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.setDataSource(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.<init>(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:97)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.getExceptionTranslator(JdbcAccessor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:645)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:680)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:707)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:757)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:192)
```

Comment: The nested SQLException about connection already closed suggests a code or possibly config issue.  Please update with the code that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If retrieving those 400 rows from the database take some time, I assume you are hitting DB connection timeout. If so, increase `connectionTimeout` if you are using resource pool. Timeout could happen while you are debugging the code, too.

Could also be that timeout is on the database side. In that case, you'll have to tweak DB timeout parameters.